# When using a fetch request in a Node JS server it receives the body as blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I was working on a user login system in Node JS and was making a POST request to the server like this.

```
let data = {
    username: "John Doe",
    password: "123abc",
}

let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
}

fetch('/verify-login', options).then(function(r) {
    return r.text();
}).then(function(dat) {
    if (dat == 'n') {
        document.getElementById('login-fail').innerHTML = 'User name or password is incorrect!';
    } else {
        console.log('Login Success');
    }
});
```

Server Side code:

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 80;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.post('/verify-login', async function(q, r) {
    let dat = await q.body; //<-- Body is just {} not what the fetch request sent

    //do account check stuff with dat

    if (success) {
        r.send('y');
    } else {
        r.send('n');
    }
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Started application on port %d", port);
});
```

This issue is that on the server side when I receive the request, the body is returned with '{}'. Does anybody know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: `let dat = await q.body; ` — Express middleware will popular `body` with a plain object, not a promise. `await` is pointless here.

Comment: To clarify, you need to replace `body: data,` with `body: JSON.stringify(data),`

Comment: Don't just silently edit your code...

Comment: I've removed `await`, I'm logging `dat`, and added `app.use(express.static('./public'));`. Works perfectly fine as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various data types you can pass to `fetch` through the `body` option.

If you pass something it doesn't recognise, it converts it to a string and sends that.

Converting a plain object to a string doesn't give you anything useful.

```js
let data = {
    username: "John Doe",
    password: "123abc",
}

console.log(`${data}`);
```

You said you were sending JSON (with the `Content-Type` header. So you need to actually send JSON.

```
const json = JSON.stringify(data);
```